# CSS: legend in the same row as fieldset

Tags: html, css

I've a stars rating system and I want to put some legend on it (so it is not only the stars icons).

As I'm using Bootstrap4, I was thinking on using a row, and 2 cols to align them horizontally, however, my legend keeps getting some pixels above my stars.

I've also tried using `margin-top: 10px` on the legend, without the desired result.

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

        fieldset, label {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 20px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        /****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

        .rating {
            border: none;
            float: left;
        }

        .rating > input {
            display: none;
        }

        .rating > label:before {
            margin: 5px;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            display: inline-block;
            content: "\f005";
        }

        .rating > .half:before {
            content: "\f089";
            position: absolute;
        }

        .rating > label {
            color: #ddd;
            float: right;
        }

        /***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

        .rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
        .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
        .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
            color: #FFD700;
        }

        /* hover previous stars in list */

        .rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
        .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
        .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
        .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label {
            color: #FFED85;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                <fieldset class="rating hidden text-center">
                                    <legend>Califícanos: </legend>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star5"
                                                                                                   title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star4half"
                                                                                                         title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star4"
                                                                                                   title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star3half"
                                                                                                         title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star3"
                                                                                                   title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star2half"
                                                                                                         title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star2"
                                                                                                   title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star1half"
                                                                                                         title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star1"
                                                                                                   title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                        for="starhalf"
                                                                                                        title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GevVYZ

[image]

I've also tried using `span` tag:

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

        fieldset, label {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 20px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        /****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

        .rating {
            border: none;
            float: left;
        }

        .rating > input {
            display: none;
        }

        .rating > label:before {
            margin: 5px;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            display: inline-block;
            content: "\f005";
        }

        .rating > .half:before {
            content: "\f089";
            position: absolute;
        }

        .rating > label {
            color: #ddd;
            float: right;
        }

        /***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

        .rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
        .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
        .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
            color: #FFD700;
        }

        /* hover previous stars in list */

        .rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
        .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
        .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
        .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label {
            color: #FFED85;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                <span class="calificanos-text hidden">Califícanos: </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                <fieldset class="rating hidden text-center">

                                    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star5"
                                                                                                   title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star4half"
                                                                                                         title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star4"
                                                                                                   title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star3half"
                                                                                                         title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star3"
                                                                                                   title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star2half"
                                                                                                         title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star2"
                                                                                                   title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star1half"
                                                                                                         title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star1"
                                                                                                   title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                        for="starhalf"
                                                                                                        title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rRGBvB

This is what I see in my html (localhost):

What I see locally:

[image]

Comment: Don't link to the code pen. Display the relevant code here.

Comment: @cmprogram, thank you, modified question.

Comment: you want them like the first pic or the second?

Comment: @godfather 1st if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped them all in the div col6 and set them to display flex and then i removed the margin 5px in .rating > label:before

```css
        @import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
/* NEW */
.col-md-6.col-lg-6 {
    display: flex;
}
 .rating > label:before {
            
            font-size: 1.25em;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            display: inline-block;
            content: "\f005";
        }
/* END */
        fieldset, label {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 20px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        /****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

        .rating {
            border: none;
            float: left;
        }

        .rating > input {
            display: none;
        }

       

        .rating > .half:before {
            content: "\f089";
            position: absolute;
        }

        .rating > label {
            color: #ddd;
            float: right;
        }

        /***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

        .rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
        .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
        .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
            color: #FFD700;
        }

        /* hover previous stars in list */

        .rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
        .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
        .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
        .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label {
            color: #FFED85;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                <span class="calificanos-text hidden">Califícanos: </span>
                           
                                <fieldset class="rating hidden text-center">

                                    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star5"
                                                                                                   title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star4half"
                                                                                                         title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star4"
                                                                                                   title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star3half"
                                                                                                         title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star3"
                                                                                                   title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star2half"
                                                                                                         title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star2"
                                                                                                   title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                         for="star1half"
                                                                                                         title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"/><label class="full"
                                                                                                   for="star1"
                                                                                                   title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5"/><label class="half"
                                                                                                        for="starhalf"
                                                                                                        title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: hope that this what you want